# Parameterized query in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

I am new in PostgreSQL and trying to get parameterized query to work. I have following sql statements where type A seems to be ok but type B does not work.

sql type A)

```
 StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("Select * from JOB where")    
 buffer.append(" START_TIME ");
 buffer.append(" BETWEEN '2020-08-17' AND '2020-08-18'");
 String sql = buffer.toString();
```

sql type B) - parameterized

```
 StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("Select * from DA_JOB where")    
 buffer.append("START_TIME");
 buffer.append(" BETWEEN ? AND ?");
 String sql = buffer.toString();
```

execute query based on the type - executing type A is successful but type B is not

```
try (Connection dbConnection = getConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
      if (typeB) {
             //myHashMap<String, String> holds some key value

              StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder("'");
              String value = myHashMap.get("startTime")
              st.append(value);
              st.append("'");
              statement.setString(1, st.toString());                
              
              StringBuilder st1 = new StringBuilder("'");
              String value2 = myHashMap.get("endTime")
              st1.append("'");
              statement.setString(2, st1.toString());
      }
      try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                 jobs.add(sanitize(rs));
             }
        } 

 }
```

the error I get from executing parameterized query which is type B is

> "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
> timestamp without time zone >= character varying\n  Hint: No operator
> matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add
> explicit type casts.

which seams to be quotation problem in the final query after setting string.
Any tips on how I can fix this? It is really appriciated.

Comment: Drop the additional quote marks in the append statements. That's needed in a SQL literal, but not in a prepared statement. Just setString.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus   it does not work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that the DB engine is refusing to cast your string into a date. There are two approaches you can take to fix this. One is to add a cast server-side. `BETWEEN ?::date AND ?::date` should work. The `::` is a PostgreSQL non-standard cast; you can also use SQL-compliant CAST syntax if you want.

An alternative would be to use preparedStatement's `setDate`, creating a java.sql.Date object from your stored String (or storing a Date in your HashMap).

Comment: To add to this, `.setString(1, y);` where y is a thing that __includes__ the single quotes is not how preparedstatements work in the first place. You pass the actual string you want (so, if you include single quotes, those are actually in the string then). I'm pretty sure Andrew is right and you can't .setString() to pass date args (even though you CAN in raw SQL mode), but if you could, certainly you need to remove those single quotes first.

Comment: I used the first approached and worked .. thanks @Andrew Lazarus .. I have a question for my understanding - when we use `?::date` what does it do? does it cast it to date object. if so how setString works on date object? sorry if the question is naive

Comment: We all were new to this sometime. the ::date is a cast from string to date. You could also, for different data, have ::time, ::boolean, etc. setString doesn't tell the DB anything about the parameter except that it can be expressed as a string (so, pretty much anything). setString on a date object would fail to compile, but setString(1, myDate.toString()) would work. And then with the ::date, the DB would turn it back into date format again. By the way, moving dates in and out of String representation is slow. Don't do this in code that needs to be fast.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus thanks for explaining it in an easy way